# How to create file and return it via FileResult in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have to create and return file in my aplication ASP.net MVC aplication. The file type should be normal .txt file. I know that i can return FileResult but i don't know how to use it.

```
public FilePathResult GetFile()
{
string name = "me.txt";

FileInfo info = new FileInfo(name);
if (!info.Exists)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = info.CreateText())
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Hello, I am a new text file");

    }
}

return File(name, "text/plain");
}
```

This code doesn't work. Why? How to do it with stream result?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**EDIT ( If you want the stream try this: )**

```
public FileStreamResult GetFile()
{
    string name = "me.txt";

    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(name);
    if (!info.Exists)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = info.CreateText())
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Hello, I am a new text file");

        }
    }

    return File(info.OpenRead(), "text/plain");

}
```

You could try something like this..

```
public FilePathResult GetFile()
{
    string name = "me.txt";

    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(name);
    if (!info.Exists)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = info.CreateText())
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Hello, I am a new text file");

        }
    }

    return File(name, "text/plain");

}
```

Comment: Also consider the other options- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187261/whats-the-difference-between-the-four-file-results-in-asp-net-mvc remembering that File( can accomodate all of them.

Comment: Yea, the File([params],...) will do what you want...you need to figure out what u want...

Comment: In the second example you must replace declaring name variable to file path.    string name = Server.MapPath("/me.txt");

Answer (score 8):

Open the file to a `StreamReader`, and pass the stream as an argument to the FileResult:

```
public ActionResult GetFile()
{
    var stream = new StreamReader("thefilepath.txt");
    return File(stream.ReadToEnd(), "text/plain");
}
```

Comment: Note that `"thefilepath.txt"` needs to be the full path to the text file, not just a relative path.

Comment: how can i create one? with "TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("date.txt");" or something else?

Comment: Yes, for example like so. Remember that the file paths need to be full paths, and use `using` statements.

Answer (score 3):

Another example of creating and downloading file from ASP NET MVC application at once but file content is created in memory (RAM) - on the fly:

```
public ActionResult GetTextFile()
{
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] contentAsBytes = encoding.GetBytes("this is text content");

    this.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    this.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + "text.txt");
    this.HttpContext.Response.Buffer = true;
    this.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
    this.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(contentAsBytes, 0, contentAsBytes.Length);
    this.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
    this.HttpContext.Response.End();

    return View();
}
```