# ASP.NET MVC2: How to return a file from a controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create file and return it via FileResult in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375486/how-to-create-file-and-return-it-via-fileresult-in-asp-net-mvc)

ASP.NET MVC2: How to return a file from a controller?

I want to do this so the user can download the file from server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375486/how-to-create-file-and-return-it-via-fileresult-in-asp-net-mvc *Hint*: `FileResult` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
        public ActionResult Csv(int pid)
        {
            var csv = this.Repo.GetCsv(pid);
            var fileContents = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(csv);
            return new FileContentResult(fileContents, "application/vnd.ms-excel") { FileDownloadName = "Report-" + pid + ".csv" };
        }
```