# ASP .NET MVC - Have a controller method that returns an image in the response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I make a controller method called `GetMyImage()` which returns an image as the response (that is, the content of the image itself)?

I thought of changing the return type from `ActionResult` to `string`, but that doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: what do you mean 'returns an image' what Type is it at that time?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Return [FilePathResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filepathresult.aspx) using [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492492.aspx) method of controller

```
public ActionResult GetMyImage(string ImageID)
{
    // Construct absolute image path
    var imagePath = "whatever";

    return base.File(imagePath, "image/jpg");
}
```

There are several [overloads of File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492897.aspx) method. Use whatever is most appropriate for your situation. For example if you wanted to send Content-Disposition header so that the user gets the SaveAs dialog instead of seeing the image in the browser you would pass in the third parameter `string fileDownloadName`.

Comment: Wow, you gotta love ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [FileResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.aspx) class. For example usage see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375486/how-to-create-file-and-return-it-via-fileresult-in-asp-net-mvc).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `FileContentResult` like this:

```
byte[] imageData = GetImage(...); // or whatever
return File(imageData, "image/jpeg");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;     
using System.IO;

public ActionResult Thumbnail()
{
    string imageFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/tempimg/sti1.jpg");
    var srcImage = Image.FromFile(imageFile);
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    srcImage.Save(stream , ImageFormat.Png);
    return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/png");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try one of these depending on your situation (copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image)):

```
public ActionResult Image(string id)
{
    var dir = Server.MapPath("/Images");
    var path = Path.Combine(dir, id + ".jpg");
    return base.File(path, "image/jpeg");
}


[HttpGet]
public FileResult Show(int customerId, string imageName)
{
    var path = string.Concat(ConfigData.ImagesDirectory, customerId, @"\", imageName);
    return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), "image/jpeg");
}
```