# serve CSV file from web service call

Tags: .net, web-services, csv, export-to-csv

Using code such as:

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = True
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/CSV"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.csv")
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = ""
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(csvString.ToString())
    HttpContext.Current.Response.[End]()
```

Can I serve a CSV file from a web service call. It doesn't seem to work what am I missing?

I have set up a traditional `asp:button` and this serves the file correctly, though the web service returns a 500 server error `Thread was being aborted`

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, that should be text/CSV

Answer (score 0):

you can return a byte array for files. Read up on [Accept and Return file to/from C# WebService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912495/accept-and-return-file-to-from-c-sharp-webservice)

That being said, and this is personal taste, I like to keep my web services "clean" in that they only return XML. They are, after all, for inter-machine communication and file transfer has its own protocol in FTP so there's that. Behavior like what you're looking for should, as far as I feel, be isolated into a generic (ashx) handler that can be called whenever needed. Again, that's taste.

an excerpt from an ashx handler could look like this:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/CSV";
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" 
   + fileName +  "\"");
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
context.Response.Flush();
```