# Using LINQtoCSV in MvcScaffolding ASP.NET Web Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to add a link to a basic MvcScaffolding project that outputs all data from a IQueryable interface.  The controllers are built with `Scaffold Controller Sales -Repository` and have nothing out of the ordinary in the Sale class, just a few strings and some integers.  Everything in the project works as expected.

From posts I've found, LINQtoCSV could be a possible solution for me (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library).  Unfortunately, I don't know what to add. If I have a link on the index page of /Sales/ that points to /Sales/CSV/, how can prompt the user with "Download or Open"?

I also saw this page (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) that tells how to build a Web API, but I cannot use MVC 4 per company standards.

The code I currently have in `SalesController.cs` is the following (which errors with `[DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\...\Sales\CSV\LINQtoCSV.CsvContext'.]`):

```
    //
    // GET: /Sales/CSV/
    [Authorize]
    public FilePathResult CSV()
    {
        List<Sale> dataRows = saleRepository.All.ToList();

        CsvFileDescription outputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
        {
            SeparatorChar = '\t', // tab delimited
            //EnforceCsvColumnAttribute = false,
            FirstLineHasColumnNames = true, // no column names in first record
            FileCultureName = "en-US" // default is the current culture
        };
        CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();

        cc.Write<Sale>(dataRows,
            "output.csv",
            outputFileDescription);

        return File(cc.ToString(), "text/csv");
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Modified code to create list from repository and output using File().

**EDIT:**
This is the modified code that I'm using.  In the model, I'm building the string with a joined list.  The controller code is as follows:

```
    [Authorize]
    public FileStreamResult CSV3()
    {
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output);
        saleRepository.All.ToList().ForEach(s => writer.WriteLine(s.ToStringCSV));

        writer.Flush();
        output.Position = 0;

        return File(output, "text/csv", "report.csv");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to use the [FileResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.aspx) class? See also [How to create file and return it via FileResult in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375486/how-to-create-file-and-return-it-via-fileresult-in-asp-net-mvc)