# How to convert a pdf to a memory stream

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing an application in MVC4.

I have a physical pdf file on the server. I want to convert this to a memory stream and send it back to the user like this:

```
return File(stream, "application/pdf", "myPDF.pdf");
```

But how do I convert a pdf file to a memory stream?

Thanks!

Comment: I would not say "convert". Given that a pdf in file form IS a stream of bytes that is no conversion. Why do you need a memory stream? Any stream should do, and guess what, there is a file stream.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create file and return it via FileResult in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375486/how-to-create-file-and-return-it-via-fileresult-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need `MemoryStream`. Easiest way is to use overload that accepts file name:

```
return File(@"C:\MyFile.pdf", "application/pdf");
```

another solution is to use overload that accepts `byte[]`:

```
return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Myfile.pdf"), "application/pdf");
```

or if you want use `FileStream`:

```
return File(new FileStream(@"C:\MyFile.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), "application/pdf");
```

Answer (score 6):

Worked it out

```
 var pdfContent = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imageLocation));
                pdfContent.Position = 0;
                return new FileStreamResult(pdfContent, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: This isn't bad, but this allocates a lot of memory unnecessarily. You lose the advantage of having a physical file that can be *streamed*.

Answer (score 1):

Use an overload that uses a filename, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492593%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). It's the easiest solution when you have a physical file.