# What would be the most efficient way of converting a pdf to a stream

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a `WCF` service that will receive an id and return a pdf file based off of the id. I am assuming that the best way to do this would be to convert the pdf file to some sort of string and then return it. However, I am unsure of which stream to use (`Stream, Filestream, or MemoryStream`).

I know i could read the pdf file to a byte array and then do something with it using MemoryStream, but I feel like there is a more efficient way.

I tried doing what was suggested in this post here: [How to convert a pdf to a memory stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826999/how-to-convert-a-pdf-to-a-memory-stream)

Hard coding a file path in to return like so:

```
return File(@"C:\MyFile.pdf", "application/pdf");
```

Just to see what happens, but get an error on `File` saying: `'System.IO.File' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'.

Would anyone be able to provide a little insight?

**EDIT**

This is currently what I am working towards:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "/GetInvoiceFile")]
Stream GetInvoiceFile(string id);

public Stream GetInvoiceFile(string BillingPeriodId)
{
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\pdf-test.pdf");
    return new MemoryStream(bytes);
}
```

I just dont exactly know how I would edit my `OperationContract` to return the pdf. Any ideas?

Comment: `File` is a helper function for MVC controllers and is not applicable to WCF.

Comment: @DStanley - I should have figured that would be the issue. What would be an efficient way to do this with `WCF`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what you have. You seem to have the path to a file as a `string`. Probably, your WCF method returns a `byte[]`. You somehow need to convert that path to a `byte[]` efficiently.

You can do this using `File.ReadAllBytes(string path)`.

WCF also supports streaming writes but that is a little more complicated and the performance wins are dubious for small files.

The fact that you tried to specify a MIME type (`"application/pdf"`) tells me that you do not really understand the difference between a WCF service and an HTTP service. Researching this is homework for you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I do already have the file set to a `byte[]`. I think i would like to write it to a stream for now at least. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What does your WCF method return? A byte[]? Your fixation on streams seems unfounded.

Comment: To answer your question literally: The most performant and easiest way to convert a byte[] to a Stream is new MemoryStream(myByteArray). I doubt this is what you need, though.

Comment: Currently I have my method set up to return a Stream.

Comment: OK. Make it return a byte[]. If you don't want that for some reason use the stream solution that I provided. This will *not* give you streaming semantics since you're loading the entire file into memory first. Does this answer your question fully?

Comment: To give you a better idea with what i am working with please see my edit above. I understand the `OperationContract` is not correct. I am unsure how i would adjust it though. I have not worked with WCF that much prior to this so it is all a learning experience. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebInvoke. I can't answer that part of the question and I would not have posted an answer if I had know that this is the real problem for you. I have answered the stream part though: new MemoryStream(myByteArray)

Comment: As far as answering my question goes, you have helped a great deal. You just seemed knowledgeable so i figured i would ask. Thank you for the help.