# Exporting Excel File to View (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel

I have to Export Data to View as Excel , Actually I have Implemented,but my doubt is when 
to use

```
return new FileContentResult(fileContents, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

**vs**

```
return File(fileContents, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

and How can set Downloadable Filename in each of this methods?

Example 1:

```
public ActionResult ExcelExport()
{
   byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
   return new FileContentResult(fileContents, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
}
```

Example:2

```
public ActionResult ExcelExport()
{
   byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
   return File(fileContents, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can read about the differences between FileContentResult & FileResult here : [What's the difference between the four File Results in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187261/whats-the-difference-between-the-four-file-results-in-asp-net-mvc)

You can specify the filename like this

```
return new FileContentResult(fileContents, "application/vnd.ms-excel") { FileDownloadName = "name.xls" };

// or

// note that this call will return a FileContentResult object
return new File(fileContents, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "name.xls");
```