# Return Files in methods of a Control in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, c#-4.0

I Have an Upload Manager and I want to return a File when user called a special Method of My Control Like this:

```
www.website.com/upload/getfile/?fileID=100
```

how Can I do this?
**I want to know how Can I return a file!**

---

I found my answer and I wrote the sample code below:

```
public FilePathResult GetFile(string Name)
    {
        FilePathResult s = new FilePathResult(@"C:/"+Name, "File");
        Response.Headers.Clear();

        return s;
    }
```

but there is a problem now.Is there any problem if I use `File` for my ContentType.Because I don't know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a controller named `uploadController`, with an action named `getfile` which has an argument.

Then the above url can be changed to

```
www.website.com/upload/getfile/100
```

**UPDATE:**

Change the return type of action to `FileResult`

For complete answer take a look at part of my codebase:

```
//Attachment Class
public class Attachment
{
    #region Properties

    public virtual Guid AttachmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual int? ContentLength { get; set; }
    public virtual string ContentType { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] Contents { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateAdded { get; set; }
    public virtual string FileName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    #endregion
 }


public class AttachmentController : Controller
{
     IAttachmentService attachmentService;

    public AttachmentController(IAttachmentService attachmentService)
    {
        this.attachmentService = attachmentService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
    {
        var attachment = this.attachmentService.GetById(id);
        return attachment.IsNull() ? null : this.File(attachment.Contents, attachment.ContentType,attachment.FileName);
    }
}

public class AttachmentModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase httpRequestBase = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        HttpPostedFileBase @base = httpRequestBase.Files[bindingContext.ModelName];
        var converter = new FileConverter();
        Attachment attachment = converter.Convert(
                new ResolutionContext(
                    new TypeMap(new TypeInfo(typeof(HttpPostedFileWrapper)), new TypeInfo(typeof(Attachment))),
                    @base,
                    typeof(HttpPostedFileWrapper),
                    typeof(Attachment)));
        }
        return attachment;
    }
}

public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(Attachment)] = new AttachmentModelBinder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the ViewResult to FileResult.

Comment: fore more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187261/whats-the-difference-between-the-four-file-results-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: It worked but I don't know what is ContentType and I couldn't find any Result in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.aspx

Comment: It should be one of these types http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to return a FileResult http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
public void getFile(fileId id) 
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = GetFileInfo(id); //Your function, which returns File Info for the Id
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
    Response.TransmitFile(fileInfo.FullName);
    Response.ContentType = "CONTENT TYPE";
    Response.Flush();
}
```

I was using this to get MP3 file from server.

Hope this helps.