# Make a file open in browser instead of downloading it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an MVC project that will display some documents to users. The files are currently stored in Azure blob storage.

Currently, the documents are retrieved from the following controller action:

```
[GET("{zipCode}/{loanNumber}/{classification}/{fileName}")]
public ActionResult GetDocument(string zipCode, string loanNumber, string classification, string fileName)
{
    // get byte array from blob storage
    byte[] doc = _docService.GetDocument(zipCode, loanNumber, classification, fileName);
    string mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
    return File(doc, mimeType, fileName);
}
```

Right now, when a user clicks on a link like the following:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://...controller//GetDocument?zipCode=84016&loanNumber=12345678classification=document&fileName=importantfile.pdf
```

Then, the file downloads to their browser's downloads folder. What I would like to happen (and I thought was default behavior) is for the file to simply be displayed in the browser.

I have tried changing the mimetype and changing the return type to FileResult instead of ActionResult, both to no avail.

How can I make the file display in the browser instead of downloading?

Comment: Pretty sure the browser decides how to handle the file based on the mimeType.  http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml

Comment: That's what I suspected too, so I tried various mimetypes associated with .pdf's and attempted to open the file, but it downloaded each time. When I view other pdf's on other sites they open in the browser window.

Comment: What's the value of the content-disposition header?

Comment: Header Response: Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=importantfile.pdf

Comment: Yep.  That's your problem.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Thanks to all the answers, the solution was a combination of all of them.

First, because I was using a `byte[]` the controller action needed to be `FileContentResult` not just `FileResult`. Found this thanks to: [What's the difference between the four File Results in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187261/whats-the-difference-between-the-four-file-results-in-asp-net-mvc)

Second, the mime type needed to NOT be a `octet-stream`. Supposedly, using the stream causes the browser to just download the file. I had to change the type `application/pdf`. I will need to explore a more robust solution to handle other file/mime types though.

Third, I had to add a header that changed the `content-disposition` to `inline`. Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-pdf-files-to-open-in-browser) I figured out I had to modify my code to prevent duplicate headers, since the content-disposition was already being set to `attachment`.

The successful code:

```
public FileContentResult GetDocument(string zipCode, string loanNumber, string classification, string fileName)
{
    byte[] doc = _docService.GetDocument(zipCode, loanNumber, classification, fileName);
    string mimeType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
    return File(doc, mimeType);
}
```

Comment: More robust solution for getting mimetype: `return File(doc, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName));`

Comment: Awesome you got it solved.  The link I put in the comment above will allow you to create a dictionary based on file extensions for MimeTypes.  Then, just create a static function that takes a file extension and returns a MIME type for any file you are expecting (I probably wouldn't cover .crt for instance).  If an extension is not found, return the standard *application/octet-stream*

Comment: Worked like a charm! Best solution.

Comment: _More robust solution_ really works, wouldn't it need to be placed/edited in the the main answer..  ??

Comment: Do the files being displayed in the browser window leave a footprint in the file system of the client or the server?
I have Personally Identifiable Info on the files i'm displaying and I need to make sure that the viewed file is not viewable outside of the web application

Comment: @jplara I don't think you can do that. If it's a native app you may be able to restrict it, but otherwise you'll need a wrapper of some sort. It's a PDF in the answer so if the browser opens it, the user can choose to save it, copy from it, etc. I do have a similar issue, but the risk is the automatic downloading of unwanted/unknown copies of that personal data to multiple client machines, not the risk of the user deliberately saving it, which actually may be required at times.

Comment: As soon as i specify a file name, the file will be downloaded instead of previewing in browser. Firefox is the only exception, as far as i know, which gives user a choise whether to show or download the file. The name must be specified if dynamic mimetype is used to avoid strange names or extensions.

Answer (score 17):

It looks like someone else asked a similar question a while ago:

[how to force pdf files to open in a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-pdf-files-to-open-in-browser)

With an answer saying that you should use the header:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename.pdf
```

Comment: Ok, so unfortunately I tried this, and had to follow the steps in the linked post, but it still does not work. I tried changing the return type to FileContentResult and that also did not help.

Comment: This was definitely part of the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Browsers should decide on downloading or displaying based on mime-type.

Try this:

```
string mimeType = "application/pdf";
```

Answer (score -2):

Just return PhysicalFileResult and use HttpGet method ,url will open pdf file

```
public ActionResult GetPublicLink()
{
     path = @"D:\Read\x.pdf";
    return new PhysicalFileResult(path, "application/pdf");
}
```