# Use Response.Redirect to open pdf in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How to dynamically open file resource in browser using Response call in C# and ASP.NET?
I have a file server that stores documentation. I have another server that runs IIS and ASP.NET application. I need to open a pdf document stored on the file server in a browser window.
I supply folderPath string as "\\MyFileServer\documentFolder\" and filename string as "doc.pdf". I try to redirect to

```
Response.Redirect(folderPath + filename, true);
```

but redirection tries to append my provided location of the resource to current server path. I'm new to ASP.NET so please forgive me my ignorance.
Oh, BTW, the site is accessed from android tablets so I need explicitly redirect client browser to a file resource, otherwise android will start downloading the file instead of opening it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a response, write a Header:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; doc.pdf
```

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411335/make-a-file-open-in-browser-instead-of-downloading-it)

Comment: Thx for the answer. I tried it but nothing happens. Almost like some execute command was missing after this one.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Response.AddHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524327%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

You can do something like

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + filepath + ".pdf");
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. I tried it but nothing happens. Almost like some execute command was missing after this one. Browser keeps displaying my test.aspx.

Comment: @ArtK: Is your filepath includes file extension? if it is remove the extension which added manually. Otherwise it may result `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename.pdf.pdf")`

Comment: I tested path string as seen by browser by sending it to Response.Write(). When I knew that is was correct I used it in Response.AddHeader(). There is no action when the call gets executed.

Comment: @ArtK: Its difficult to say what is happening. Have a look at [this](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/11/aspnet-open-pdf-file-in-web-browser.html) and try