# MVC : Open PDF directly in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filestream

I followed this post of stack overflow

[Make a file open in browser instead of downloading it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411335/make-a-file-open-in-browser-instead-of-downloading-it)

It works perfectly in firefox and chrome but internet explorer still gives open/save popup.
 However when you select to open, it does open the file in the browser but is there any way for that popup to not come at all in IE like in other browsers?

**Edit**

Also, how can we give the name to the window/tab that opens the pdf

Comment: Take a look at https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/cant-view-pdf-web.html. You probably need to enable an option or install a plugin.

Comment: @Ian - I don't think it is something related to missing or broken plugin because if that would be the case it would not open the pdf at all.

Comment: As you described the problem I thought it was being downloaded then opened by Acrobat reader.