# ASP.net. Mime type of a downloaded file not detected by browser

Tags: asp.net, file, types, mime

I'm trying to return a PDF file in asp.net just by returning File(). The contents of my File are as expected except its MIME type which is not recognized by the browser. I wonder what could be the workaround with this.The users want to see the pdf on the fly with the browser internal viewer, but without the correct MIME tipe that doesn't seem to be possible.

this is how I return the PDF.

```
return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf", "Reporte" + nVista + ".pdf");
```

And this is firefox uncapable of recognizing its type. Same thing with chrome.

[this is not an HTML document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcKEz.png)

Comment: Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"

Comment: I'm assuming this is MVC? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19412687/5947043

Comment: Samuil suggestion doesn't make any difference whatsoever, the browser still won't detect the MIME type.
I'll try the answer on that link, and see what happens. Thanks.