# Difference between FileContentResult and FileStreamResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I'm editing some code and there is one method which return `FileContentResult` type. I get a stream from service, so for me it would be more convenient to change returning type to `FileStreamResult`.

Should I convert stream to an array to return `FileContentResult`?

Or can I just change returning type safely?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`FileResult` is an abstract base class for all the others.

- `FileContentResult` - use it when you have a byte array you would
  like to return as a file
- `FileStreamResult` - you have a stream open, you want to return it's
  content as a file

Reference: [What's the difference between the four File Results in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187261/whats-the-difference-between-the-four-file-results-in-asp-net-mvc/1187270#1187270)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1187270

Answer (score 56):

Both `FileStreamResult` and `FileContentResult` inherit from `FileResult` which inherits from `ActionResult`. So you can return either one type from a method which has `ActionResult` as the return type

If you already have a **stream,** you can use `FileStreamResult` constructor to return a `FileResult`

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    var f = Server.MapPath("~/Content/mypdf.pdf");
    var fileStream = new FileStream(f,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
    return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(f));
}
```

If you already have a **byte arrray**, you can use `FileContentResult` constructor to return a `FileResult`

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    var f = Server.MapPath("~/Content/mypdf.pdf");
    var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(f);
    return new FileContentResult(bytes, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(f));
}
```

The `Controller.File` method has overloads which takes either a byte array or a stream

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    var f = Server.MapPath("~/Content/mypdf.pdf");
    var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(f);
    return File(bytes, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(f));
}
public ActionResult Download2()
{
    var f = Server.MapPath("~/Content/mypdf.pdf");
    var fileStream = new FileStream(f, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    return File(fileStream, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(f));
}
```

If the browser has the support to display the content type of the response, the response will be displayed in the browser. For example, for the above code, it will display the pdf content in the browser.

There is another overload of the `File` method which takes the download file name which the browsers' save/download dialog will use so that user can save it his local computer and/or  open.

```
public ActionResult Download4()
{
    var f = Server.MapPath("~/Content/mypdf.pdf");
    var fileStream = new FileStream(f, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    return File(fileStream, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(f),"MyfileNiceFileName.pdf");
}
```

With this, user will get a download prompt from the browser.

Comment: The client can't tell the difference. The client cannot find out what .NET class was used to send bytes to the browser.

Comment: What if I need to show file to a particular section of webpage. Currently filestream will render the entire web page. Can we target a small area in a page?

Comment: I guess you can try to load in an iframe. Never tried it myself though

Comment: This is wrong. Either method can either force a download *or* render directly in the browser window (assuming the content type is something the browser is capable of handling). It just depends on what overload your use.