# how to specify name for saving pdf from browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, pdf, browser

ASP.NET MVC 4 controller returs pdf:

```
    public ActionResult Pdf()  {

        byte[] result = CreatePDF();
        var ms = new MemoryStream(result);
        return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
    }
```

Results appears in Chrome browser window.
If user right-clicks in pdf and selects Save as Chrome offers `Pdf.pdf` as file name to save.

How to specify other default file name like `Order 123.pdf` ?

Chrome Developer Tool show that file nime is not speficied in response:

```
Cache-Control:private, s-maxage=0
Content-Length:30814
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Fri, 14 Oct 2016 19:18:09 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `File` method.

```
public FileResult Pdf()  
{
    byte[] result = CreatePDF();
    string fileName = "Order 123.pdf";
    return File(result, "application/pdf", fileName);
}
```

There is no need to wrap `result` in `MemoryStream`

Comment: In this case pdf is not shown in Chrome. Only downloaded file icon appears. How to force browser to show pdf immediately, without extra click in downloaded file in this case ?

Comment: @Andrus, according to [answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19412687/1380428) you need to set `Content-Disposition: inline`

Answer (score 0):

`FileStreamResult` has a `FileDownloadName` property which you can set

```
public ActionResult Pdf()
{
    byte[] result = CreatePDF();
    var ms = new MemoryStream(result);
    var fs = new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf") {FileDownloadName = "Hello.pdf"};
    return fs;
}
```

This is exactly what happens when you call the `ControllerBase.File` method's [overload which takes the file name](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L642).

```
public ActionResult Pdf()
{
    byte[] result = CreatePDF();      
    return File(result ,"application/pdf","Hello.pdf");
}
```

Comment: If `FileDownloadName` is specified or `File` result is returned pdf is not shown in Chrome. Only downloaded file icon appears and extra click is required to show pdf. How to force browser to show pdf immediately, without extra click in downloaded file ?

Comment: If you are trying to download. this depends on the user browser (download) settings. Based on the settings it will either download the file to your download folder or open to the user. If you absolutely want to show the file to use.  You should use FileStringResult. In that case, there is no reason to specify a file name(user is not going to download it). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498184/difference-between-filecontentresult-and-filestreamresult/34498356#34498356)

Comment: User may want to save order and expect that offered file name contains order number