# How To Open File According To There File Extension Format Without Downloading File?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

Here i am trying to open the file of any extension format in `ASP.NET MVC CORE 2.0` that has been saved in data base according to the extension format of that file without downloading that file. For example lets say i have ms word file so when i click that file it should open in word, if i have pdf it should open in pdf format without downloading the file.
Now, the problem in my code is that it force to download the file instead of opening the file according to respective file extemsion format.
 
Any help will be a great and  will be thank full.Thank You
Below is my code

```
  public IActionResult ViewFileByFileId (int id)
    {
        DoctorCredentialDocsModel DoctorCredential = new DoctorCredentialDocsModel();
        DoctorCredential = _doctorService.GetDoctorCredentialDetails(id);
        string AttachPath = ConfigPath.DoctorCredentialsAttachmentPath;
        string strFileFullPath = Path.Combine(AttachPath, DoctorCredential.AttachedFile);

        string contentType = MimeTypes.GetMimeType(strFileFullPath);
        if (!strFileFullPath.Contains("..\\"))
        {
            byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(strFileFullPath);
            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = DoctorCredential.FileName,
                Inline = false,
            };
            Request.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            return File(filedata, contentType);
        }
        else
        {
            return new NotFoundResult();

        }
    }
```

Comment: how can you open file without downloading it? Do you mean "download and open in browser"?

Comment: it should open according to there extension format without downloading, it's 
 like returning file to view before download

Comment: but with `return File(filedata, contentType);` you sending whole file content, how your browser can reject to download it?

Answer (score 0):

Try yo send like tihs. FileContentResult may can help you :)

Lastly look at this :)

[What's the difference between the four File Results in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187261/whats-the-difference-between-the-four-file-results-in-asp-net-mvc)

```
 public FileContentResult  ViewFileByFileId (int id)
    {
        DoctorCredentialDocsModel DoctorCredential = new DoctorCredentialDocsModel();
        DoctorCredential = _doctorService.GetDoctorCredentialDetails(id);
        string AttachPath = ConfigPath.DoctorCredentialsAttachmentPath;
        string strFileFullPath = Path.Combine(AttachPath, DoctorCredential.AttachedFile);

        string contentType = MimeTypes.GetMimeType(strFileFullPath);
        if (!strFileFullPath.Contains("..\\"))
        {
            byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(strFileFullPath);
            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = DoctorCredential.FileName,
                Inline = false,
            };
            Request.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            return File(filedata, contentType);
        }
        else
        {
            return new NotFoundResult();

        }
    }
```

Comment: No sir it didn't solved my problem , whenever i click on word file it get downloaded in browser which is what i don't want i want it to get open in word file

Comment: What about pdf file?

Comment: No it is downloading in browser

Comment: Try to force content type  application/ms-word"; in manuel in your code, may mime type is not detect.

Comment: If this is not work, last advice like this, use StremReader library and fill with your dbData. You have to search on the internet about  StremReader  a bit